# How to include a web site in a jsp

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I need to include a web page in my jsp file. i.e: `https://www.google.com`

I tried both `<s:include>` and `<include>`, but it didn't work.
Please give me an example for that. Project is use Struts2 Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe).

> The `<iframe>` element represents a nested browsing context.

For example:

```xml
<body>
    <span>The following is an i-framed content:</span>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com" width="600" height="600">
    </iframe>
</body>
```